# Elepahs: Spark+Keras - Creating an RDD from numpy arrays for large data

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, machine-learning

I am using Elephas for machine learning over Spark: https://github.com/maxpumperla/elephas

As given at the above link:

## Code To Create an RDD from numpy arrays is as below:

```
import numpy as np
# Step 1: Load data from file into memory
train_data = np.loadtxt('../data/train.csv', delimiter=',')
labels = train_data[:,0]
pixels = train_data[:,1:]
data_size = train_data.shape[0]
tuple_size = pixels.shape[1]
print ('size of training data: ', data_size)
print ('size of training tuple: ', tuple_size)
print (labels.shape)
print (pixels.shape)

# Step 2: Create RDD from Training Data in Memory
training_data = pixels
training_labels = labels
trX = training_data / 255
data_size = training_data.shape[0]
trX = trX.reshape(-1,1,28,28)
trY = np.zeros((data_size,5), dtype=theano.config.floatX)
row = 0
for row in range(data_size):
    trY[row,training_labels[row]] = 1
    row = row + 1
rdd = to_simple_rdd(sc, trX, trY)
...
```

With this code, I am able to load training data using numpy for 350MB of training data, without issue, But when the data is large (8GB), I am short of memory and program does not go after line np.loadtxt

Is there any way I can solve this by:
1. Optimizing memory consumed by NumPy (So, that 8 GB fit in 32GB RAM)
2. Copy Training Data on Each Node and Create a RDD without loading whole data into memory ( like sc.textfile() )

Please help.